# is there a way to fopen a file that allows me to edit just a few bytes?

Tags: c++, io

I am writing a class that compresses binary data using a zlib stream. I have a buffer that I fill with the output stream and once it becomes full I dump the buffer out to a file using `fopen(filename, 'ab');...` What this means is that my program only opens up the file to write to it whenever it has a buffer full of data to dump, it goes and does it and immediately closes it.

The issue is in my format I use an 8 byte header at the beginning of each file which contains the original length and compressed length but I do not know these values until the end of the whole compression process.

What I wanted to do was write 8 bytes of zeros, then append with all my compressed data, then come back at the end during cleanup to fill in those 8 bytes with the size data, but I can't seem to find a way to open the file without bringing it all back into memory. I just want to edit the first 8 bytes of the file. Do I need to use `mmap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the file in append mode, you do need to close and re-open it:

1. open with `fopen(filename, "r+b")`;
2. write the 8 bytes;
3. close the file using `fclose()`.

The `r+` means

> Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned  at  the
>   beginning of the file.

and the `b` is needed to open in binary mode.

You can use this method to change the data at any position in the file, not just at the beginning: simply use `fseek()` to seek to the required position before writing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`rewind()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/rewind/) to take the file pointer back to the start of the file after you write out the last few bytes of data. You can then output your 8 bytes of length info.

Comment: Doesn't work on the `FILE*` used to write the last few bytes of data, because the file was opened for appending.

Comment: @steve: append just means move the pointer to the end of the file automatically. It's still open for writing, so you can rewind/seek anywhere you want.

Comment: Try it and see. Append mode means that all writes are to the end of the file, regardless of the current seek position.

Comment: Well, poop.. .ain't that just silly. Oh well, answer still holds, just reopen the file in regular write mode and seek to 0.

Comment: That's why I remember it, because it wasn't what I was expecting. When I was caught out by it, I was implementing `fwrite`.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to use the `r+`. I somehow missed it while reading over the options

Answer (score 1):

If you have flexibility in changing your format, I might suggest this.  Define your compressed stream such that it is a sequence of an unknown number of blocks, and each block is preceded by a fixed length integer specifying the number of bytes in the block.  The stream is finished when the next block has a size of zero.

The drawback to this format is that there no way for the reader of the stream to know how much data is coming until it's all been read.  But the advantage is that it avoids this problem you are trying to solve.

More importantly, it allows you to send a compressed stream of data somewhere as you read the input and you don't have to save it all before sending it.  For example, you could write a compression Unix filter that you could put in a pipe stream:

```
prog1 | yourprog -compress | rsh host yourprog -expand | prog2
```

Good luck.